# UIImagePickerController pushed on my own UINavigationalController?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to take the `UIImagePickerController` set to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` (ie when it allows the user to take a picture) and push it on my own `UINavigationalController` but it doesn't work (can't push a `UINavigationalController` onto another `UINavigationalController`).

I'm wondering, is there anyway to make a custom version of this camera module, much like you can do with the  `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` `UIImagePickerController` using `ALAssets`? I'd just like to not have to pop up the camera as a modal view and would like to push it on my own `UINavigationalController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom camera using `AVFoundation`.

Refer [Sample AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) for how to use AVFoundation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that the `UIImagePickerController` is itself a UINavigationController, so pushing that onto a navigation controller is going to have problems (as you've already found)

As Prince has mentioned, your best bet is to use the AVFoundation to create your own. The downside is you'll (by default) lose the nice features of the camera app such as touch to focus, pinch to zoom etc. but these can all be added yourself.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821) which gives you a nice explanation on how to use the AVFoundation library for this, and also shows you how to add things like an overlay to the camera screen. Then you can easily find on google/stackoverflow how to add things like tap to focus :)